# how to get cpu load linux java in percent precise and easy way?

Tags: java, linux

Hi I am trying to get cpu load but I want to get just cpu load in percent. I have my code as shown below what the easiest way to get it as I try this code bu using net

```
OperatingSystemMXBean operatingSystemMXBean = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
    for (Method method : operatingSystemMXBean.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
      method.setAccessible(true);
      if (method.getName().startsWith("get")  && Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
        Object value;
        try {
          value = method.invoke(operatingSystemMXBean);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          value = e;
        } // try
      System.out.print(method.getName() + " = " + value);
```

hopes for your reply

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to use Sigar API, you can use it for extracting different metrics. I have also used this for my application, you can refer the following link

http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home

Answer (score 1):

Create a timer and take the sum of all Thread CPU times every second. Maybe this way:

```java
long cpuTime = 0;
for (long id : ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean ().getAllThreadIds ())
{
    cpuTime += ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean ().getThreadCpuTime (id);
}
```

The CPU percentage is then the relative cpu time between the last and the current second divided by the timestamp difference.

Here's a simple example implementation of a `CpuStats` Class:

```java
public class CpuStats
{
   private final long threadId;
   private long lastCpuTime = 0;
   private long lastPoll = 0;

   /**
    * Creates a CpuStats object for a single thread.
    * @param threadId The id of the thread to monitor
    * 
    */
   public CpuStats (long threadId)
   {
      this.threadId = threadId;
      lastCpuTime = getTotalTime ();
      lastPoll = System.nanoTime ();
   }

   /**
    * Creates a CpuStatus object for all threads. The supplied statistics affect
    * all threads in the current VM.
    */
   public CpuStats ()
   {
      threadId = -1;
      lastCpuTime = getTotalTime ();
      lastPoll = System.nanoTime ();
   }

   private long getRelativeTime ()
   {
      long currentCpuTime = getTotalTime ();
      long ret = currentCpuTime - lastCpuTime;
      lastCpuTime = currentCpuTime;

      return ret;
   }

   public double getUsage ()
   {
      long timeBefore = this.lastPoll;

      lastPoll = System.nanoTime ();
      long relTime = getRelativeTime ();

      return Math.max ((double)relTime / (double)(lastPoll - timeBefore), 0.0);
   }

   private long getTotalTime ()
   {
      if (threadId == -1)
      {
         long cpuTime = 0;
         for (long id : ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean ().getAllThreadIds ())
         {
            cpuTime += ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean ().getThreadCpuTime (id);
         }

         return cpuTime;
      }
      else
      {
         return ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean ().getThreadCpuTime (threadId);
      }
   }
}
```

Just retrieve `getUsage()` periodically.

Answer (score 1):

This code using `mpstat` may be a solution

```
import java.io.*;
public class CpuLoad {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      int i=1;
      float finalres;
      try{
        // execute the linux command
        Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mpstat");
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line=null;
        //read the row corresponding to cpu idle
        while((line=in.readLine())!=null && i<4){         
          i++;
        }       
        String res=line.substring(line.length()-5);
        finalres=Float.parseFloat(res);
        //convert the idle to cpuload
        System.out.println("CPU load:"+(100-finalres)+"%");
      }
      catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
      }
  }
}
```

[Source](http://www.cipherbase.co.in/2014/01/java-program-to-find-cpu-load-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class :

```
        import com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean;
        import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

        public class PerformanceMonitor {
            static long lastSystemTime      = 0;
            static long lastProcessCpuTime  = 0;
            static int  availableProcessors = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean().getAvailableProcessors();
            public synchronized double getCpuUsage()
            {
                if ( lastSystemTime == 0 )
                {
                    baselineCounters();
                  //  return ;
                }

                long systemTime     = System.nanoTime();
                long processCpuTime = 0;

                if ( ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean() instanceof com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean )
                {
                    processCpuTime = ( (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean() ).getProcessCpuTime();
                }

                double cpuUsage = (double) (processCpuTime - lastProcessCpuTime ) / ( systemTime - lastSystemTime )*100.0;

                lastSystemTime     = systemTime;
                lastProcessCpuTime = processCpuTime;

                return cpuUsage / availableProcessors;
            }

            private void baselineCounters()
            {
                lastSystemTime = System.nanoTime();

                if ( ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean() instanceof com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean )
                {
                    lastProcessCpuTime = ( (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean) ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean() ).getProcessCpuTime();
                }
            }

        }
```

And then call :

```
    public class Main {

        public static PerformanceMonitor monitor = null;


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            monitor = new PerformanceMonitor();
            for(int i=0 ; i<10000 ; i++){
                start();
                double usage = monitor.getCpuUsage();
                if(usage!=0)System.out.println("Current CPU usage in pourcentage : "+usage);
            }
        }

        private static void start() {
            int count=0;
            for(int i=0 ; i<100000 ; i++){
                count=(int) Math.random()*100;
            }
        }
    }
```

You can also take a look at other monitoring methods, hope it'll helps!

EDIT : (new Performance Monitor)

```
    import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;


    public class PerformanceMonitor {
        static long lastSystemTime      = 0;
        static long lastProcessCpuTime  = 0;
        public static int  availableProcessors = ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean().getAvailableProcessors();
        public synchronized double getCpuUsage()
        {
            ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().setThreadCpuTimeEnabled(true);
            if ( lastSystemTime == 0 )
            {
                baselineCounters();
              //  return ;
            }

            long systemTime     = System.nanoTime();
            long processCpuTime = 0;

            processCpuTime = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
            double cpuUsage = (double) (processCpuTime - lastProcessCpuTime ) / ( systemTime - lastSystemTime )*100.0;

            lastSystemTime     = systemTime;
            lastProcessCpuTime = processCpuTime;

            return cpuUsage / availableProcessors;
        }

        private void baselineCounters()
        {
            lastSystemTime = System.nanoTime();

            lastProcessCpuTime = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
        }

    }
```

Comment: would it give me accurate result ??

Comment: Yes I think, I have not other comparizon bases but I add use it with memory management and result where quite accurate in comparizon with JVM ones for examples. It's probably good for CPU usage too

Comment: Look at the edit, mb I've not explain it very well... Create an instance of `PerformanceMonitor` only once.

Comment: still it is not showing any output you have change in the caode in the second part ?

Comment: Yes I change the second part (add static). First part is in the class, I put the instanciation in main for example. And the last call in a loop that execute a method for example. you copy/paste the code with all imports?

Comment: I put an example of class using it

Comment: i used this class as you mentioned me and after changing i try it but result is empty :(

Comment: If you copy both classes and execute it works. I think if you get nothing in an other case it's because your cpu usage is equals to 0%. I add an other PerformanceMonitor class, maybe this one will works for you.

Comment: yup you are right but i wanna get its result in this format like 60% etc while i am getting like this when i print it in loop (run:
Current CPU usage in purcentage : 66666.66666666666
Current CPU usage in purcentage : 2801.1204481792715
Current CPU usage in purcentage : 20408.163265306124
Current CPU usage in purcentage : 750.7507507507507
Current CPU usage in purcentage : 27027.027027027027
Current CPU usage in purcentage : 29411.764705882353
Current CPU usage in purcentage : 19607.843137254902
Current CPU usage in purcentage : 606.7961165048544)

Comment: Yes I add those strange result sometimes when I do empty loop for example. But with the new PerformanceMonitar class (see the EDIT) I have not this problem any more.

Comment: thanks alot for your help can you please tell me the logic that you have used in this class for getting cpu load ?? and more over i am now getting the result in this format (Current CPU usage in purcentage : 50000.0
Current CPU usage in purcentage : 50000.0
Current CPU usage in purcentage : 220.99447513812157
Current CPU usage in purcentage : 1367.9890560875513
Current CPU usage in purcentage : 1367.9890560875513) how would i cahang e it to in this format like (Current CPU usage in purcentage =60%)

Comment: how would i check the cpu load comming from this procedure with the cpu load in real ?

Comment: Sorry if you get those strange result again, I thought I get rid of it... Btw the logic is simple. I check the real time and CPU time T-1 then I check both times at T and then I do : `(double) ( [CPU_T-1] - [CPU_T] ) / ( [TIME_T-1] -  [TIME_T] )*100.0`

Comment: are you getting right result like 60% .. etc ?? using this code

Comment: Yes I have no problem with last one, even without code in the start() loop I get result like 25.107359429933222%. Maybe you call getUsage() at some bad moment. I don't know what cause those high percentage, maybe it's the call to nanotime? Mb try currentTimeMillis? But I don't think it'll fix it. Tell me what you get just with the 2 classes I gave (using the last one in edit ofc)?

Comment: with the first class i get this result (Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 103.5539723303786
Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 79.06388361796331
Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 299.6703626011387
Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 130.14055179593961)

Comment: And with the edit new performance i am getting (Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 76.94971336231772
Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 83.28475056217208
Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 187.2308556450103
Current CPU usage in pourcentage : 421.05263157894734)

Comment: Ok I think my method is not enough accurate for your need. I don't really understand why you get so much result over 100%. The last thing I can imagine is that the number of `availableProcessors` is not the same as your hardware really is.

Comment: I think you are right i have 1 cpu having two cores ??? then my processor value will be 2 ?? perhaps it will do my result correct ?

Comment: Yes 1 dual-core CPU = 2 processors. Try to replace current method with `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());` if you get wrong count.

Comment: where would i use this line ?

Comment: I class PerformanceMonitor instead of `public static int  availableProcessors = ===> ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean().getAvailableProcessors();<===
` if this one don't give you the good result.